# Mail logging script does not work

Tags: php, linux, shell, email

for the last 2 days, i am struggling with this script. If anyone knows, why it does not work, please let me know.

I have done the modification based on this solution: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-log-emails-sent-with-phps-mail-function-to-detect-form-spam#comment-23670

Basically, I want to find out, Whether this Email is originating from black list or not.

```
#!/bin/sh
TMPFP=`mktemp`

cat | tee "$TMPFP"

echo "Processing....." >> $LOGFILE

for i in `cat /root/scripts/email/email-blacklist.txt`
do
echo "Inside the loop; Processing.....$i" >> $LOGFILE

grep "X-PHP-Script" $TMPFP | grep $i >> $LOGFILE

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
#It is a spammy domain, Don't send Emails.
echo "Mail Originating from Spammy Domain $i" >> $LOGFILE
cat $TMPFP  >> $LOGFILE
rm -f "$TMPFP"
exit ;
else
continue ;
fi
done
```

Result of cat
cat /root/scripts/email/email-blacklist.txt

```
aaa.com
bbb.com
cccc.com
dddd.com
```

This script does not even enter into the loop.
This script does not even reach this line
echo "Inside the loop; Processing..

Comment: Do you get to the first "Processing....." line? How are you running that script? Is it being fed input via standard input?

Comment: Found the soln.
For loop was not able to read the file which is in /root/ folder.
Problem: for i in `cat /root/scripts/email/email-blacklist.txt`